# Rails 3 has_many :through is only adding id from on side of the relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through

I am trying to move from a has_many, belongs_to relationship to a has_many :through relationship with my Project and User model. However when I test it in the rails console only one side of the relationship seems to get set in the join model.

I currently have it set up like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :users, :through => :collaborations
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :projects, :through => :collaborations
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then in the console I'm typing in:

```
me = User.find(1)

p = Project.new(:name => "somename")
p.users << me
p.save
```

And what happens is that the Collaboration model gets the project_id set but not the user_id.

And the opposite happens (the user_id gets set but not the project_id) when I do something like this:

```
me.projects << p
```

Basically, it creates a "Collaboration" but only one side of the relationship gets saved.

I have been stuck at this for hours now and I feel like it's something minor - maybe something left over from when I was doing the one-to-many relationship between these two models.

---Edit---
This is what the schema looks like:

```
create_table "collaborations", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "shared",      :default => false
  t.integer  "position",    :default => 0
  t.string   "permalink"
  t.text     "description"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "crypted_password"
  t.string   "password_salt"
  t.string   "persistence_token"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "role"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "perishable_token",  :default => "", :null => false
  t.integer  "avatar",            :default => 0
end
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What does your schema look like for the projects, collaborations, and projects?

Comment: Just added it in there for you

Comment: my apologies -- I meant, if you use `collab = Collaboration.last`, what are its `project` and `user` values? If either of these show up nil, try `collab(true).project`, etc, which forces it to reload. Does that help?

Comment: Just tried, I get the same result :(

This is what shows up when I check for the collaborations (notice the user_id:nil).

#<Collaboration id: 17, project_id: 116, user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-01-19 02:52:24", updated_at: "2011-01-19 02:52:24">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship in a roundabout way. Your `Collaboration` model looks exactly like a join model.

I'd suggest going with a proper `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. Basically, what you have will become:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

And then you'll need to create a migration for the join table:

```
def self.up
  create_table :projects_users, :id => false do |t|
    t.references :project, :user
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_table :projects_users
end
```

You should then be able to do `User.find(123).projects` and `Project.find(321).users`, as well as the `<<` you're trying to do. For further explanation of how `has_and_belongs_to_many` works, as well as the various methods you can use on the associations, please see the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: Right, I was just trying to do the has_many :through incase I need more flexibility in my Collaborations later on. I will still give this method a try and see if I get a result

Comment: Well that worked like a charm! If I need further flexibility in the join later on, I'll deal with it then I guess.. but it still bothers me why it wasn't working with has_many :through